# Density of disconnected graph

Tags: python, networkx

Let's say I have a disconnected graph, with components:

```
G:
    Node     Edge
    1         2
    2         3
    3         1
    4         1
    5         7
    7         8
    12        6 
    6         1
    9         10
    10        11
```

How can I determine the density of the network? Would it make sense to calculate the density of the full network or I should consider individual networks and densities? The graph is undirected. The function I have found for calculating density is `density()` in network.

Comment: That clearly depends on your use case. The `density` function in networkx will give you the ratio of edges to nodes - and will not check for connectivity. If you e.g. want to measure the "sparsity" of your network, then you can take the usual definition.